# How to validate dynamic Custom JSP tag attribute using TagExtraInfo?

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, jsp, jsp-tags

I have created custom JSP tag and it`s working fine but having problem in attrib validation.

```
<tt:qu userName='<%= request.getParameter("Username") %>'/>

public class TEI extends TagExtraInfo {
public boolean isValid( TagData tagData ) {


    String jdriver = (String) tagData.getAttribute("userName");
//error at this line.
```

but getting error

**java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    tag.TEI.isValid(TEI.java:12)**

Answer (score 0):

If this is happening on the server, you need to figure what the type really is.  If it isn't a String, you can't cast it as one.

Answer (score 0):

String jdriver = (String) tagData.getAttribute("userName").toString();

just call the toString method on object and assign to string